Why there are two similar functions in the contract?

This image comes from the immunefi github splitter.sol. I am stuyding how to write down the compensation logic for decentralized bug bounty. It seems like those two functions are similar and changeFeeRecipient calls _changeFeeRecipient. So, I understand they don't want to show the content of _changeFeeRecipient. However, the code is open-sourced. Why there are two functions exist?

Two Functions, One Goal: Secure Access.
Basically the contract could have two things that seem alike, but they're actually different because only certain people can use each one

Internal Function: Think of this function as a special room in the contract. Only the other functions inside the contract can go inside and use it.

Public Function (with access control): Imagine this function as a gate with a guard. Anyone can try to enter by calling it, but only specific users, such as the owner of the contract, are allowed in because of special rules called access control. Once the right person is in, this function then directs them to another part of the contract to get the job done


so this separation keeps things secure by restricting who can directly modify sensitive data.
